# Re-evaluating style with Windows Phone

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to implement a sort of theming mechanism in my Windows Phone 8 app, what I'm doing is getting a setting from persistent storage and resolving that into a style which is referenced :

```
Style="{Binding Source={StaticResource ThemeLocator}, Path=GetThemePanoBackground}"
```

Where `ThemeLocator` returns a style from Application Resources defining the background.

This works quite well but when the theme is changed and I go back to a previous page, the style is not re-evaluated. I have tried to look into `DynamicResource` but I cannot seem to get any good reference on how to use it for Windows Phone or if it's even supported or would work for my use-case.

Any suggestions as to the method involved is welcomed!

**edit**

Unless I absolutely have to use the following in the `NavigatedTo` event and set it explicitly:

`control.Style = ThemeLocator.GetThemePanoBackground;`

Comment: Windows Phone theme manager does something similar. You might want to take a look on the source code. http://www.nuget.org/packages/PhoneThemeManager.Source/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not too thrilled with the method but this works. If anyone else has some input that would be great.

```
        if (ApplicationState.ThemeUpdated)
        {
            Control.ItemTemplate = null;
            Control.ItemTemplate = (DataTemplate)Application.Current.Resources["CustomTemplate"];
        }
```

The control style is completely re-evaulated along with other bindings which works out great.